# Error In Importing react Component

Tags: reactjs

I am facing the following error when I am trying to Import a component in react.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replaceChild' of null
at Function.replaceChildWithTree (index_bundle.js:4067)
at Object.dangerouslyReplaceNodeWithMarkup (index_bundle.js:21337)
at Object.dangerouslyReplaceNodeWithMarkup [as replaceNodeWithMarkup] (index_bundle.js:7162)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._replaceNodeWithMarkup (index_bundle.js:22799)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._updateRenderedComponent (index_bundle.js:22789)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._performComponentUpdate (index_bundle.js:22739)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.updateComponent (index_bundle.js:22660)
at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performUpdateIfNecessary (index_bundle.js:22576)
at Object.performUpdateIfNecessary (index_bundle.js:4277)
at runBatchedUpdates (index_bundle.js:1846)
```

My Component is:

```
import React from 'react'


export default class NoticeCard extends React.Component {


    render() {
            return (
                    <section className="centered white">
                            <div className="container section">
                                    <div className="center">
                                              <p>Invalid Username/Password </p>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                    </section>
            )
    }
```

}

The Component is rendered in but the console throws the error.

Comment: is there another error in the console before this one?

Comment: no. this is the only error. it occurs when I change state of the parent component to render the Noticecard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is just a symptom, there is a crash somewhere in your code that is being swallowed.

It could be an indication that the DOM has been modified outside of React's control (parent is null, so when replacing a child it tries to call replaceChild on null). Make sure the parent component is not being changed to null or undefined.

check this thread: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6998

and especially this comment:
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6998#issuecomment-263336611

Comment: thanks. I solved the problem after understanding the error.